# How to append text to a scrolling box?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, text, scroll

I am currently using a scrolling box with the content "Some Text" inside the box:

```
<style>
.scroll {
background: #ff8e00;
height: 150px;
overflow: scroll;
width: 200px;
border: 1px solid #000;
padding: 10px;
} 
</style>

    <div class="scroll">
     Some Text
</div>
```

The appearing text is a part of the div element.
Now my goal is to create a text element in d3.js and append it to the scrolling box. The text element looks like this :

```
<script>

var width = 600;
var height = 300;

var svg = d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)    
      .attr("height", height); 


     var text = svg.append("text")
        .attr("dx", 1)
        .attr("dy", 1)
        .text("Some New Text."); 

</script>
```

I want that "Some New Text." appears in the box. Maybe some of you guys could help me out with this problem. Thanks.

Comment: maybe it is relevant, because there is nothing wrong with what you gave, it's out of context.

Comment: Do you mean the left out parts of the code? It's just some basic stuff which takes alot of place.

Comment: Is this a HTML text or a SVG text? What is `svg` selection?

Comment: It is a svg text. I just edited the code.

Comment: If you want to append an SVG to that div and then append a text to the SVG, just do `var svg = d3.select(".scroll")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this snippet helps.

```js
var width = 600;
var height = 300;

var svg = d3.select("div.scroll") //Selects div with the class scroll
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var text = svg.append("text")
  .attr("dy", "1em")  //Updating relative coordinate y
  .text("Some New Text.");
```

```css
.scroll {
  background: #ff8e00;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroll">
  Some Text
</div>
```